# How can I locate inferred latches in Xilinx ISE?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I have a big design in Xilinx ISE, there are 3 inferred latches which I would like to remove. Threre is no IP core or Microblaze and I have written all the code myself. I have problem locating the latches in my design. I have searched through report files but non helped me. Is there a method to quickly find them??? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can search your synthesis report (*.syr file) for the XST warning 737:

> WARNING:Xst:737 - Found `<n>`-bit latch for signal `<name>`.

`<n>` and `<name>` should be replaced by proper wildcards :)

The BEL report at the end of your synthesis report will list `L*` primitives (e.g. `LD`) in the flip-flop section. Normal flip-flops are named `FD*` (e.g. `FDRCE`).